# Trying to save file without using SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, text-editor, savefiledialog

I am creating a text editor and i am stuck on the SaveFileDialog window opening
and asking to overwrite the current file open.

I have seen all the similar questions asked like this on SO but none have been able to help me. I have even tried the code from this question: "Saving file without dialog" [Saving file without dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429083/saving-file-without-dialog?rq=1)

I got stuck on my program having a problem with FileName.

Here is the code i have currently

```
namespace Text_Editor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Clear();
        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

            open.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            open.Title = "Open File";
            open.FileName = "";

            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.Text = string.Format("{0}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(open.FileName));
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(open.FileName);
                richTextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

            save.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            save.Title = "Save File";

            save.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(save.FileName);
                writer.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }

        private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saving = new SaveFileDialog();

            saving.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            saving.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            saving.Title = "Save As";
            saving.FileName = "Untitled";

            if (saving.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamWriter writing = new StreamWriter(saving.FileName);
                writing.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
                writing.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So my question is how can i modify my code so that i can save a file currently open without having the SaveFileDialog box opening everytime?

I do understand that it has something to do with the fact that i'm calling .ShowDialog but i don't know how to modify it.

Comment: Then don't call it...

Comment: So you want the user to enter the filename in a textbox or what?

Comment: If you know the path to the file, just use it and do not show the dialog.

Comment: Yes i understand i must not call it but i dont know how to modify my code in order not to call it. If the user has a open text file and they modify it, it should just save when the hit save. not open a dialog asking where it must be saved.

Comment: Alex i think i understand what you are saying. Please could you elaborate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When opening the file, save the `FileName` in a form-level variable or property.

Now while saving the file, you can use this FileName instead of getting it from a FileOpenDialog.

First declare a variable to hold filename at form level

```
// declare at form level
private string FileName = string.Empty;
```

When opening a file, save the FileName in this variable

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

    open.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    open.Title = "Open File";
    open.FileName = "";

    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // save the opened FileName in our variable
        this.FileName = open.FileName;
        this.Text = string.Format("{0}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(open.FileName));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(open.FileName);
        richTextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

And when doing `SaveAs` operation, update this variable

```
private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saving = new SaveFileDialog();

    saving.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

    saving.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    saving.Title = "Save As";
    saving.FileName = "Untitled";

    if (saving.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // save the new FileName in our variable
        this.FileName = saving.FileName;
        StreamWriter writing = new StreamWriter(saving.FileName);
        writing.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
        writing.Close();
    }
}
```

The save function can then be modified like this:

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FileName))
    {
        // call SaveAs 
        saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
    } else {
        // we already have the filename. we overwrite that file.
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(this.FileName);
        writer.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

In the New (and Close) function, you should clear this variable

```
private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // clear the FileName
    this.FileName = string.Empty;
    richTextBox1.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a new string variable in your class for example
    string filename = string.empty

and then

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)) {
 //Show Save filedialog
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

    save.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    save.Title = "Save File";

    save.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

    if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filename = save.FileName;

    }
   }
   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
        writer.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
        writer.Close();
}
```

The SaveFileDialog now only opens if fileName is null or empty

Answer (score 2):

You will have to store the fact that you have already saved the file, e.g. by storing the file name in a [member variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms173113.aspx) of the `Form` class you have. Then use an `if` to check whether you have already saved your file or not, and then either display the `SaveFileDialog` using `ShowDialog()` (in case you haven't) or don't and continue to save to the already defined file name (stored in your member variable).

Give it a try, do the following:

- Define a `string` member variable, call it `_fileName` (`private string _fileName;` in your class)
- In your `saveToolStripMenuItem_Click` method, check if it's `null` (`if (null == _fileName)`)
- If it is `null`, continue as before (show dialog), and after getting the file name, store it in your member variable
- Refactor your file writing code so that you either get the file name from the file dialog (like before), or from your member variable `_fileName`

Have fun, C# is a great language to program in.

Answer (score 1):

First, *extract method* from `saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click`: what if you want add up a *popup menu*, *speed button*? Then just implement

```
  public partial class Form1: Form {
    // File name to save text to  
    private String m_FileName = "";

    private Boolean SaveText(Boolean showDialog) {
      // If file name is not assigned or dialog explictly required
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_FileName) || showDialog) {
        // Wrap IDisposable into using
        using (SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog()) {
          dlg.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
          dlg.Title = "Save File";
          dlg.FileName = m_FileName;  

          if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) 
            return false;

          m_FileName = dlg.FileName;  
        } 
      }

      File.WriteAllText(m_FileName, richTextBox1.Text);

      this.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(m_FileName);

      return true;
    }

    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      // SaveAs: always show the dialog 
      SaveText(true);
    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      // Save: show the dialog when required only
      SaveText(false);
    }
    ...
  }
```